# Image tracking - tracking a screen with a camera

Tags: opencv, image-processing

I want to track the relative position of a camera aimed at a computer screen.

I can’t control what is displayed on the computer screen but I can receive screen dumps whenever something changes on the screen. Those screen dumps can hopefully be used to find the screen when analyzing the video from the camera.

I see many videos on youtube for face, logo or single colored objects tracking using OpenCV but I’m unsure those methods would work finding and tracking a more detailed image like a screen dump.
Maybe Template Matching is the way to go? But I need to find the screen even at an angle.
Basically I don’t know where to begin and need help from people with experience in this field to find the best way for achieving what I want.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using feature matching should do the trick (Sift/SURF/ORB/...)